# Make child elements of Linear Layout not clickable when parent isn't

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout stored as `app_view`.

There is a time when I slide the `app_view` over for a sidebar. At this time, I'd like to turn everything in `app_view` to not be clickable.

I don't want the little sliver of the layout to be clickable while the sidebar is displayed.

I've tried setting `app_view.setClickable(false)`, but that doesn't seem to set the clickable on all child elements maybe?

What's the best way to approach this type of situation?

Comment: Why? I've included every bit of code that is necessary for this question.

Comment: `app_view.setClickable(false)` will give the click to child. It will not solve your problem. :) I guess may be you can try a `onTouchListener` on `app_view` and return `true`.

Comment: no luck setting the onTouchListener and just returning true/false. Both still allow the elements to be clicked.

Comment: A simple recursive function which iterates over `app_view`'s children and sets clickable to false should do the job.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a "correct way" of doing things though.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void setClickableRecursive(View view, boolean isClickable){
    if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
        for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++){
            setClickableRecursive(group.getChildAt(i), isClickable);
        }
    }else{
        view.setClickable(isClickable);
    }
}
```